# How to make button open the frame in a relevant language?

Tags: java, jframe, actionlistener, multilingual

I have two classes, each one with JFrame.

The first frame contains two buttons, they are supposed to open the next frame in a proper language. My task is: I open the first frame (start program), I want to choose english language, I click on the button with "English" label, it opens the next frame with program. All labels, all buttons are in English.

When I want it to be in e.g. French, I click French button in the first frame, and the second one opens with all labels and button in French

So, my question is this: how to combine action with clicking on the button with opening the frame in a proper language?

Currently all buttons opens the same frame with labels in one language.
Here is a sample of my code of the first frame and "View" is the next JFrame in next class View:

```
public class StartFrame extends JFrame {
    JButton button1 = new JButton(new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon("flag.png")).getImage()).getScaledInstance(100, 75, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
    JButton button2 = new JButton(new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon("flag2.jpg")).getImage()).getScaledInstance(100, 75, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));    
    public StartFrame() {
        setSize(480,360);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

        add(panel2);
        panel2.setLayout(null);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.white);
        panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 75));
        button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 75));

        panel2.add(button1);
        panel2.add(button2);
        panel2.add(button3);

        button1.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                View f = new View();
                f.setVisible(true);
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
                dispose();  
            }           
        });     
        button2.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                View en = new View();
                en.setVisible(true);
                en.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
                dispose();  
            }           
        });         
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StartFrame frame = new StartFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `language` field to the class `View`. Then, on your action listener you change the value of that field:

```
button1.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        View f = new View();
        f.setLanguage("French");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
        dispose();  
    }           
});
button2.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        View en = new View();
        en.setLanguage("English");
        en.setVisible(true);
        en.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
        dispose();  
    }           
});
```